# Cumulative distribution comparison for two monotonic random variables.

Tags: probability

Suppose I have two positive random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\leq Y$. Is it true that $Pr(X>y)\leq Pr(Y>y)$ for all $y\in [0,\infty]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P\{X \leq Y\} = 1$, then all the probability mass lies in the region of the plane between the $y$ axis and the line $y=x$.  Now, the event 
$\{Y > y\}$ is the disjoint union of three events:
$$\{0 < X \leq y, Y > y\}, ~ \{ Y \geq X > y\}, ~ \{X > Y > y\}$$ 
of which the
third has probability $0$ for all $y > 0$, and so
$$\begin{align*}P\{Y > y\} &= P\{0 < X \leq y, Y > y\} + P\{ Y \geq X > y\}\\
&\geq P\{ Y \geq X > y\}.
\end{align*}$$
On the other hand, the event $\{X > y\}$ is the disjoint
union of three events:
$$\{ Y \geq X > y\}, ~ \{X > Y > y\}, ~ \{X > y, Y \leq y\}$$
of which the latter *two* have probability $0$ for all $y > 0$, and
so
$$
P\{X > y\} = P\{ Y \geq X > y\}
\leq P\{Y > y\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I take it that $X\leq Y$ means that $P(X\leq Y)=1$. Under this assumption we have
$$
P(X>y)=P(X>y,X\leq Y)\leq P(Y>y,X\leq Y)=P(Y>y),\quad y\geq 0,
$$
since
$$
\{X>y,X\leq Y\}\subseteq \{Y>y,X\leq Y\}.
$$